# Matlab adding rgb to binary image side by side

Tags: matlab, image-processing, threshold

I'm supposed to add another image next to my threshold image with its original color like so: [expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya9fw.jpg)

But I'm unsure how to do it having only achieving the binary image threshold on matlab. How do I show images side by side?

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/201PI.jpg)

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

% read image
palm = imread('palmDown (2).jpg');


%split into RGB
redPalm = palm(:,:,1);
greenPalm = palm(:,:,2);
bluePalm = palm(:,:,3);

redLevel = -0.1;
greenLevel = -0.1;
blueLevel = 0.06;

redThresh = imbinarize(redPalm, redLevel);
greenThresh = imbinarize(greenPalm, greenLevel);
blueThresh = imbinarize(bluePalm, blueLevel);

colorSum = (redThresh&greenThresh&blueThresh);

colorSum2 = imcomplement(colorSum);
thumbFilled = imfill(colorSum2, 'holes');

figure;
imshow(thumbFilled); title('Sum of all');
```

Comment: you can put the two image side by side using `new_img = [left_img, right_img];`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to colorize the thresholded image. One simple way is by multiplication:

```
palm = im2double(palm); % it’s easier to work with doubles in MATLAB
palm2 = palm * thumbFilled;
imshow([palm, palm2])
```

The multiplication uses implicit Singleton expansion. If you have an older version of MATLAB it won’t work, you’ll have to use `bsxfun` instead.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I did have to use `bsxfun(@times, palm, thumbfiltered)`